# Masking of MRI in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, mask, image-segmentation

I have two images, one is a binary dicom/nifti and one is an original dicom/nifti, how I can mask binary on the original and get masked output from the original image. figure 1 is binary, figure 2 is original and figure 3 is the output sample that i need.

binary mask

[image: 1]

original

[image: 2]

the desired output I need

[image: 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

> masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(mask,orginal_img)

to get masked output .
your mask and orginal_img should be same size !!

(if it works for you please vote)

Comment: Thanks, Mahdi abbasi for your reply. can you please tell me one more thing, when I try to save it by using
nib.save(masked_img, 'main.nii')
it gives this error
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_filename'

Comment: simple multiplication gives better results like
masked_img = mask*orginal_img

Comment: @Elliot I didn't work with nib . you can save your image with cv2.imwrite('img.jpg',img) .